# Hadoop Transforming and Loading hierarchical text files

Tags: hadoop, etl

I have the semicolon separated files containing hierarchical data in the following format:

```
ParentRecord;field1;field3;field4;...;fieldN;
ChildRecordType1;field1;field3;field4;...;fieldN;
...
ChildRecordType3;field1;field3;field4;field5;field6;...;fieldN;
ChildRecordType3;field1;field3;field4;field5;field6;...;fieldN;
...
ChildRecordTypeN;field1;field3;field4;...;fieldN;
```

So there could be multiple Parent records per file and each of those records can contain N child records.

So what I'd like to accomplish is to read blocks of parent-child records and to transform them into Hadoop friendly format.

Can I accomplish this by implementing custom FileInputFormat and Custom RecordReader?
I am trying to find examples but all of them leading to LineRecord reader which is not I am trying to accomplish

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? Do you want to separate paren and child records into separate outputs or do you want to add all parent record attributes to each child record that correspond to that parent?

Comment: Ideally I would like to have those records in Hive to be able to query the data, so I believe both options are valid. For the first one I still need to add parent identifier to child records to be able to join between parent and child. Second one will add redundancy. So I believe the first option is the preferred one i.e. split the records add parent identifier to all corresponding children and produce multiple outputs to be loaded into Hive.

Comment: This is a time/space trade-off. Having to join two large tables in Hive is quite expensive. As for the storage space, compressed sequence files make this pretty much a non-issue. The biggest complication that I see is that the parent-child relationship in the source files is established by the relative position of the records. It would prevent splitting a single incoming file between the mappers. How big are the individual files and how many files have you got? Are you planning to keep getting new data incrementally over time?

Comment: The file size vary from 16mb to 300mb and there could be many files landing at the same time. It is planned to keep getting new data few times a day. You are right it is impossible to identify pos for each parent and child record, however each parent record has the same identifier, same applies to children, so logically the file can be splat.

Comment: If child records contain the id of the parent record, this should significantly simplify the load. You would have to re-merge the new data with the existing data every time the new set of files is delivered.